# Domain name isn't assigned from DHCP when booting from Live CD

Tags: network-manager, dns, dhcp, hosts

I downloaded the ubuntu 10.10 ISO image for AMD64. When i start the ISO ubuntu gets an IP address from my DHCP server. NetworkManager updates /etc/resolv.conf according to the DNS config provided by DHCP.

But NM does not apply the domain name to /etc/hosts. When i do 'hostname -f' i simple get 'ubuntu', but it should be 'ubuntu.mydomain.com'. Any ideas what's wrong here?
Is it my DHCP server or is it some missing config in ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DHCP doesn't reliably give a domain name; but really a search domain for users to be able to quickly reach other systems by their short name rather than a full domain name.

It should be up to the DHCP server to hand off IP addresses (and hostname) that will match what's in DNS, or to take the hostname passed by the machine to update DNS information. Unfortunately, we're not quite there yet.

Note, there's a long-standing bug about the behavior of hostname -f in Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netcfg/+bug/8980